# Windows 10 closing lid issue

Tags: windows-10

What else is missing? https://sendvid.com/sj4adwz7

On my Windows 10 64-bit machine, the "when I close the lid" settings is set to:

-On battery: Do nothing

-Plugged in: Do nothing

Yet after I closed the lid and open it again, I still need to press the power button just to turn the screen on. Why is it like that?

I made a custom plan and set everything to "never" but still nothing.

I play a music while lid is close and after 2 minutes it stops as well as the power light.

Comment: have you gone into advanced power management settings and are you sure that the settings are for the active plan? Also, has the computer actually gone to sleep, or just turned off the screen?

Comment: oh, apologies, i didn't realize that that was a link

Comment: in that case, have you tried creating a new plan?

Comment: custom plan did nothing

Comment: maybe your computer somehow thinks that lid close is sleep button or something? try setting sleep and power buttons to do nothing also

Comment: done, still noting

Comment: man, sorry i have no idea. that's a REALLY weird problem

Comment: hmm, what if you move a usb mouse around or something for 2 minutes. does it still sleep, or does that keep it awake, in which case, something is causing it to sleep after 2 minutes (i've actually faced that problem when using an external monitor) i can't quite recall the problem, but it was fixed by a reboot

Comment: after I did a restart, it works fine at first of closing the lid.... but goes back to the issue the second time around

Comment: ok, that <i>is</i> the same problem I was having. I believe i fixed the issue by not ever making it sleep, or not opening the lid

Comment: Ok! I experienced the same problem again! the issue arrises if you put the laptop to sleep while it is closed and connected to an external monitor, then wake it up with the external keyboard. To keep it from happening, you must wake it up by opening the lid. To keep your windows from rearranging, you can open the lid and then close it really quickly so it wakes up, but maintains the previous monitor configuration.